# C++, Math exponents

Tags: c++, math

I have this problem in making a program that helps me with this.

For n (n <= 25). Make a program that calculates and shows on the screen the value of the sum:
S= 1+ 2+ 2(pow 2)+ 2(pow 3)+...+2(pow n).

what i managed to do is this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int i;
int n;
long s;

long f() {
    if (n=0) {
        return 1;
    }else if (n=1) {
        return 2;
    }else {
        return 2* (n-1); 
    }
}
    int main()  {
        for (i=0; n<=2;++n){
            s=s+f();
                cout << s <<endl;
        }
    }
```

The main code is wrong i know that for sure but i do not know how to do it..please help me, im just a c++ begginer and trying to learn the language on my own.

Comment: I think you want [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Barry: No, he says "the main code is wrong"...

Comment: You pull in `<math.h>` but don't use the [`pow(base, exponent)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) function?

Comment: @Deduplicator Exactly. So bad question for this forum, good question for that one?

Comment: Thank you everybody for all the answers. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific things you're doing wrong...

---

```
int i;
int n;
long s;
```

Don't use globals like this. You should need no globals at all for this program.

---

```
long f() {
    if (n=0) {
        return 1;
    }else if (n=1) {
        return 2;
    }else {
        return 2* (n-1); 
    }
}
```

Here you're using recursion where you should use a loop instead. Also, `n` should be a passed-in parameter:

```
long f(int n) {
    long result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        result *= 2;
    return result;
}
```

Or even better, don't reinvent the wheel and use `pow(2, n)` instead of `f(n)`.

---

```
        for (i=0; n<=2;++n){
```

1. You set `i` but never do anything with it.
2. You never initialize `n` or `s` so they could have random values (though these days compilers are nicer to people and set all the uninitialized globals to 0, but you really shouldn't depend on that).

Ergo, you should have written `n=0` instead of `i=0`.

How it could have looked if you didn't use globals:

```
int main() {
    long s = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n <= 2; ++n){
        s += f(n);
        cout << s <<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`2(pow n)` may be written `1 << n`

or if you want to compute yourself the power of two:

```
// compute manually (1 << n)
int power2(int n)
{
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        res *= 2
    }
    return res;
}
```

Your sum is in fact `power2(n+1) - 1`, so you may simply write:

```
std::cout << ((1 << n + 1) - 1) << std::endl;
```

or

```
std::cout << power2(n + 1) - 1 << std::endl;
```

if you want to do that in loop:

```
unsigned int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    res += power2(i);
}
std::cout << res << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a geometric series. Sum of n terms of geometric series is given by:-

```
S(n) = a ( r^n - 1 )/ (r - 1 )

n = no. of terms.
r = common ratio.
a = first term.
```

So, for your example...

```
a = 1.
r = 2.
n = no of terms you want to take sum.
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a variable to hold the current sum and another variable to hold the power of 2:

```
int main()  
{
    const int n = 25;
    int pow2 = 1;
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        pow2 *= 2;
        sum += pow2;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```